# Somehow IIS site SSL certificate keeps automatically changing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ssl-certificate, iis-8

[image]

Like the attached image, for some unknown reason, the SSL certificate sometimes will automatically changes that lead me to switch it back over and over again. We have look for the pattern but can't really find any clue.

So my questions are

1. What may be the root cause?
2. Is there any way we can write a batch or anything to switch it back?

Comment: Windows HTTP API manages the certificate bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#ip-based-bindings which is quite easy to change by any other applications on the same machine, as long as they run as administrator. Therefore, it is almost impossible to know who is the culprit in the straight forward way. What certificate is being chosen at last? That certificate alone might indicate the problematic application and then you can disable it.

Comment: This [article](https://serverfault.com/questions/901865/user-permissions-to-configure-ssl-certificate-for-iis-https-binding) help me to figure out the workaround